# How to improve this MIPS-Assembly program

Tags: assembly, mips

I had this for a short exam and this is the solution I came up with. I left this subject for my last year because the teacher is really bad and I was under a lot of pressure so this is why this program is so ugly and brute forced.
The task was to take a 21 letter string and build a right pointing pyramid starting from the middle, which means 1 letter to 3 letters etc. I didn't include the second part because it is obvious of what I would do.

Out of curiosity how do I shorten this program considerably? I heard a hint that we should use swift operations but I don't know how to use them.

```
.text
.globl main

# Code goes here
main:



    #print 1st char
     
    la $t0, str
    lb $t1, 10($t0)
    
    move $a0, $t0


    li $v0, 11
    add $a0, $t1, 0
    syscall    

    jal print_endl

    jal print3

    jal print_endl

    jal print5

    jal print_endl

    jal print7

    jal print_endl

    jal print9

    jal print_endl

    jal print11
    
    jal print_endl

    jal print13

    jal print_endl

    jal print15

    jal print_endl

    jal print17

    jal print_endl

    jal print19

    jal print_endl

    jal print21





    

# Program terminates here
exit:       li $v0, 10
            syscall

# Procedure that prints a newline
print_endl: addi $sp, $sp, -4
            sw   $a0, 0($sp)

            li   $v0, 4
            la   $a0, endl
            syscall

            lw   $a0, 0($sp)
            addi $sp, $sp, 4
            jr $ra

# Procedure that prints a space character
print_spc:  addi $sp, $sp, -4
            sw   $a0, 0($sp)

            li   $v0, 4
            la   $a0, spc
            syscall

            lw   $a0, 0($sp)
            addi $sp, $sp, 4
            jr $ra

print3:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11

    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

    print5:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall

    
    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra    

    print7:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


    print9:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra    



    print11:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 5($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 15($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

    print13:
    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 4($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 5($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 15($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 16($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

    print15:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 3($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 4($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 5($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 15($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 16($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 17($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

    print17:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 2($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 3($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 4($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 5($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 15($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 16($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 17($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 18($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


    print19:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 1($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 2($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 3($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 4($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 5($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 15($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 16($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 17($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 18($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 19($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


    print21:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 11
    lb $a0, 0($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 1($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 2($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 3($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 4($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 5($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 6($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 7($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 8($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 9($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 10($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 11($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 12($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 13($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 14($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 15($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 16($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 17($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 18($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 19($t0)
    syscall
    lb $a0, 20($t0)
    syscall

    lw   $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


# Data goes here
.data

endl: .asciiz "\n"
string: .asciiz "testring123\n"
str: .asciiz "mynameisslimshadyprol"
ans: .asciiz "The length is: "
```

Comment: Code review requests should be sent to our sibling site [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctness Issues:

1. This code is following a non-standard calling convention, requiring `$a0` to be call-preserved, though in the standard calling convention, `$a0` is a call clobbered register.  While it is ok to create a custom calling convention, one should be aware of it, and, it does mean that these functions would not necessarily mix well with the C language, for example, writing one or more of them in C.
2. On MIPS, we should be using `addiu` instead of `addi` for all pointer arithmetic, including stack pointer adjustments.  While `addi` may often work, it will trap/fault on signed overflow — but pointers are unsigned numbers, so we shouldn't ask for signed overflow checking on their arithmetic.

Code Size Observations:

1. There isn't a single loop in the whole program.  Loops are one of the simplest approaches to abstraction — they allow repeating the execution of some code (the loop body) without restating that code repeatedly.
2. That code is using functions which is a good approach to abstraction.  However, no function calls any other function — only the `main` calls functions.  Functions themselves calling other functions is another opportunity to repeat code execution without restating code repeatedly.

---

When you write C code do you avoid using loops and write everything out this way?

While this works for some problems, there are many problems that cannot easily be solved without using loops<sup>1</sup> — for example, what if the string, came as input from the user and were allowed any length?  It would wholly impractical to write a loop-less<sup>1</sup> program that handles an arbitrary string.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>loops or recursion...</sub>